# Displaying Admob Ads on Android

Tags: android, admob

I'm having problems displaying ads in an Android application. I'm not seeing ads even in test mode.

The layout is taken from admob's instructions, as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/lgf.fourinarow"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <com.admob.android.ads.AdView 
      android:id="@+id/ad" 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:backgroundColor="#000000"
      app:primaryTextColor="#FFFFFF"
      app:secondaryTextColor="#CCCCCC"
      app:keywords="Android Game"
  />
</LinearLayout>
```

The mainfest is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    package="lgf.fourinarow"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
  <!-- Requires Android 2.1 or above -->
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
  <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".LGFFourInARow">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- Track Market installs --> 
    <receiver android:name="com.admob.android.ads.analytics.Inst allReceiver" android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER " />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <!-- The application's publisher ID assigned by AdMob -->
    <meta-data android:value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" android:name="ADMOB_PUBLISHER_ID"/>
  </application>
  <!-- AdMob SDK permissions -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

(I have my real publisher id in my code)
In my Java code, I have included `AdManager.setTestDevices(new String[] { AdManager.TEST_EMULATOR } );` in the `onCreate` section, to enable test mode. I've also added log messages in the `onFailedToReceiveAd`, `onFailedToReceiveRefreshedAd`, `onReceiveAd` and `onReceiveRefreshedAd` functions.
However I have still ever seen and ad, and can't see any output in the log cat.
Can anyone suggest what else I should be doing?

Answer (score 1):

You need the persmission ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
its missing.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting Internet permission before the `<application>` tag in the manifest.

```
    <!-- AdMob SDK permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Also, have you verified that you can load a web page in the browser? Sometimes the emulator has DNS problems.